# Cant acess raspberry pi 3 with posix threads

Tags: pi-3

Here is the code that runs correct as a main process

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int check;
    check = wiringPiSetupGpio();
    if(check < 0) {
        printf("Error in wiringPiSetup\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    pinMode(openPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(openPin2, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(openPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(openPin2, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100000);
    digitalWrite(openPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(openPin2, HIGH);
}
```

When I run the same code with posix thread, it doesn't effect the raspberry

```
void *actuatorRun() {
    int check;
    check = wiringPiSetupGpio();
    if(check < 0) {
        printf("Error in wiringPiSetup\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    pinMode(openPin1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(openPin2, OUTPUT);

    digitalWrite(openPin1, LOW);
    digitalWrite(openPin2, LOW);
    delayMicroseconds(100000);
    digitalWrite(openPin1, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(openPin2, HIGH);
    return 0;
}
```

I have also used the wiringPi interface for concurrent processing

> int piThreadCreate (name) ;

and no result.
Any idea why does this happen? It is seems to me like a permission problem. I run both processes with sudo. Does the thread "inherit" the permissions from the main thread?

**EDIT1**
I try to open the same devices that wiringPi open from thread and I got no Error. The problem remains.

```
if ((fd = open ("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_CLOEXEC) ) < 0) {
    printf("Thread: Cant open /dev/mem\n");
    if ((fd = open ("/dev/gpiomem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC | O_CLOEXEC) ) < 0) {
        printf("Thread: Cant open /dev/gpiomem\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you think is not working and how you have tested it is not working?

Comment: Finally it is working. The thread code is fine. I cant find what was the problem. It was something in my main process. If i find what it was I will answer it.